# Kali Linux full version on USB stick

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation, usb-drive

I have to share a pc with my brother, which is a big fan of Windows 10. I, on the other hand, want to write programs on Kali Linux. You see where this is going.

I first wanted to setup a dual boot system, but the hard drive is filled with games, so I was looking around and heard about Linux Live USB sticks. I quickly set one up, but all my data is removed after rebooting the system and the partition, the OS is running on, is just big enough to fit the filesystem and can't be resized.

Is there a way to install Kali Linux normally (no Linux Live stuff) on a standard USB stick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this not what you're looking for?

[Making a Kali Bootable USB Drive](http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install)

You said "no Linux Live stuff" but a Kali Live USB drive sounds like it's exactly what you want. Note the instructions listed there for [persistent storage](http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence).

Comment: That's what I tried, but the filesystem was permanently limited to 2.8 GB, which is the size of the operating system

Comment: @Aaron And you followed the extra instructions to add persistent storage? If yes, which filesystem was limited to 2.8 GB?

Comment: Yes, I already tried that, but I just tried it again and this time it worked. I have no idea, why it suddenly works.

Comment: Nevermind, now it refuses to boot

Comment: Boot problems aside, I think the Kali Live USB is the solution you're after. As for the boot problems and initial issues with persistent storage, it sounds like you might have a bad USB drive.

Comment: I didn't think about that. What makes a USB stick a good or bad choice?

Comment: The vast majority of USB drives should work just fine, but they sometimes  corrupt or fail. If you can, use a USB 2.0 drive from a fairly reputable manufacturer. While 3.0 and 3.1 should work a lot of motherboards have poor quality drivers and/or controllers.

Answer (score 0):

just an idea why not to install a new hard drive or To an SSD to your desktop Pc ?
Coz you can install Kali on it ,
and then follow [Kali linux HDD install](http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-hard-disk-install)

this way you share your pc resources without risk to miss with the win10